# Computing closed form summations

Tags: summation

Problem:

> Compute the close form for
> $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n (3i-1)$ as a polynomial in *n*. The closed form solution should not have a summation in it.

I am not used to working with multiple summations so I'm not sure if I erred in my process or if this is the correct solution:

> $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n  (3\sum_{k=1}^ni-1\sum_{k=1}^n)$
>
> $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n  (3(1/2n^2 + 1/2 n)- n)$
>
> $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n  (3/2n^2 + 3/2 n- n)$
>
> $\sum_{i=1}^n  (3/2\sum_{j=1}^nn^2 + 3/2 \sum_{j=1}^nn- \sum_{j=1}^nn)$
>
> $\sum_{i=1}^n  (3n^3 + 3/2 n^2- n^2)$
>
> (3$\sum_{i=1}^nn^3 + 1/2 \sum_{i=1}^nn^2)$
>
> (3n^4 + 1/2n^3)

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n (3i-1) &= \sum_{i=1}^n (3i-1)\left[\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n 1\right]\\
&=n^2\sum_{i=1}^n (3i-1)\end{align}

Can you finish off the problem?

Remark:

As you work on summation over the $k$ index, notice that the expression that is being worked on is independent of $k$. Index $k$ shouldn't influence index $i$.

Remark: Another mistake is one of the  $\frac32$ become  $3$.

Comment: if the expression that you are referring to was substituting with the expression with the index i, it would then be correct as that expansion deals with the same indexes, right?

Comment: I was referring to $(3i-1)$, as we work with $k$ index, $3i-1$ is being treated as a constant. I am not sure whether I am answering your latest question.